# "Trouble launching CVS process" when using TortoiseCVS

Tags: windows, cvs, tortoisecvs

When using TortoiseCVS, as I checkout a module, dialog (see [screenshot](http://img.skitch.com/20090104-b2pne85gp2xn9bhcgwjfsfbkcr.png)) telling me "Trouble launching CVS process", "The handle is invalid". Any idea on how this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling TortoiseCVS solved the problem. I had another concurrent install at the time of the first TortoiseCVS install, and that must have messed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Set a path to your NT cvs installation folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\CVSNT). Worked fine for me.

Comment: re-installation did not fix for me as the installer failed to write to the registry for a second time. Manually adding CVSNT to the System Path worked.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be in the form of a file URL?

is cvs.exe added to the path?

which version of tortoise?  cvs?  there was a bug reported with that description, according to google.

Comment: No, it wasn't. Looks like the initial install didn't go through as it should have (see the "answer" I added to my own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `cvs.exe` was not found in the `CVSNT` folder. I am pretty sure that I didn't delete it. Reinstalling the TortoiseCVS fixed the issue.